# Create highly customized submenu (possibly using wp_list_pages)

Tags: php, functions, core-modifications

I want to create a submenu that lists the parent page's children up to two levels. I have some code that works but I need to highly customize it. I don't understand [the codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) enough to figure out how to make this work.  This is what I need the code to look like.

For example, with a menu hierarchy of:

- Home
- Parent

  - Child 1
  - Child 2

    - Child 2.1

When on the page *Parent*, the code would look like:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="/child-1/">Child 1</a></li>
   <li>Child 2
      <ul class="child">
        <li><a href="/child-2/">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a hres="/child-2-1/">Child 2.1</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Notice the `li` with children isn't linked and it's first child has its parent's link with the title *Overview*.

This is the code I currently have:

```
<?php
    if($post->post_parent) {
      $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
    }   
    else {
      $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
    }
    if ($children) { ?>
      <ul>
        <?php echo $children; ?>
      </ul>             
    <?php } ?>
```

This code outputs:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="/child-1/">Child 1</a></li>
   <li><a class="page_item_has_children" href="/child-2/">Child 2</a>
      <ul class="child">
        <li><a hres="/child-2-1/">Child 2.1</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

I've been doing further searching and I found some code that *might* work, the only problem is, it outputs all the pages (not just the sub). And the results are all one level higher than I need (see the placement of the *Overview*).

This code:

```
<?php 
    $Pages      = wp_list_pages('title_li=&echo=0&depth=1');
    $InnerPages = wp_list_pages('child_of='.($post->post_parent != false ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID).'&title_li=&echo=0');
    $Title      = ($post->post_parent != false) ? trim(get_the_title($post->post_parent)) : trim(wp_title('', false));
    $Link      = ($post->post_parent != false) ? trim(get_the_title($post->post_parent)) : trim(get_permalink('', false));
    if($Title != '')
        $Pages      = str_replace($Title.'</a></li>',
                                  $Title.'</a>'.
                                 '<ul id="test"><li><a href="'.$Link.'">Overview</a></li>'.$InnerPages.'</ul></li>',
                                $Pages);
    echo $Pages;
    unset($Pages, $InnerPages);

    ?>
```

Outputs:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/parent/">Parent</a>
    <ul id="test">
       <li><a href="/parent/">Overview</a></li>
       <li><a href="/child-1/">Child 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="/child-2/">Child 2</a>
           <ul class="child">
             <li><a hres="/child-2-1/">Child 2.1</a></li>
           </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of working on this, I was able to loop through the results of `wp_list_pages` to customize the menu the way I needed.

```
<?php
if(count(get_post_ancestors($post->ID)) == 1 ) {
    echo '<ul>';

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent' => $post->post_parent,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();

        $child = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);

            if( count( $child ) != 0 ) : ?>
                <li class="has-children"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                <?php $children = wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0' );
                if ( $children) : ?>
                    <ul class="children">
                        <li <?php if(is_page($post->ID )) {?> class="current_page_item" <?php }?> ><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Overview</a></li>
                        <?php echo $children; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </li>

            <?php else : ?>

                <li <?php if(is_page($post->ID )) {?> class="current_page_item" <?php }?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

            <?php endif; 
        }
    echo '</ul>';
}
elseif (count(get_post_ancestors($post->ID)) == 2 ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent' => get_post( $post->post_parent )->post_parent,
        'depth' => 1,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();

        $child = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);

        if( count( $child ) != 0 ) : ?>
            <li class="has-children"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
            <?php $children = wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0' );
            if ( $children) : ?>
                <ul class="children">
                    <li <?php if(is_page($post->ID )) {?> class="current_page_item" <?php }?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Overview</a></li>
                    <?php echo $children; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>

            <?php else : ?>

            <li <?php if(is_page($post->ID )) {?> class="current_page_item" <?php }?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

            <?php endif; 
        }
    echo '</ul>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```